# Runtime error in program to create your own power function

Tags: c, math, runtime-error

Ok so I was reading the program to create your own power function given here([Write a C program to calculate pow(x,n)](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-calculate-powxn/))

I read it's 1st method which it calculates power using this function:

```
int power(int x, unsigned int y)
{
    if( y == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (y%2 == 0)
        return power(x, y/2)*power(x, y/2);
    else
        return x*power(x, y/2)*power(x, y/2);

}
```

I got the concept of this program and it gives correct results.

Now, here `power(x, y/2)*power(x, y/2)` is written so we are just calculating the square of `power(x,y/2)`. So, if my `power()` function is correct so I can just change it to `power(power(x,y/2),2)` . That is, we are just calculating the square of `power(x,y/2)`.

So, when I change my program to this:

```
int power(int x, unsigned int y)
{
    if( y == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (y%2 == 0)
        return power(power(x, y/2),2);   // Square of power(x,y/2)
    else
        return x*power(power(x, y/2),2);   // x*Square of power(x,y/2)

}
int main()
{
    int x = 2;
    unsigned int y = 3;

    printf("%d\n", power(x, y));
    return 0;
}
```

The above program gives **run-time error**.

What could be the reason for the run-time error I am not able to figure out. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: And what inputs are you passing to this function? Surely it would have been easy to supply a complete program so that we don't have to guess.

Comment: Stack overflow, as you are calling function `power` from inside itself, passing the second parameter as `2`.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling function `power` from inside itself, passing 2 as the second argument.

This is essentially an infinite recursion, which eventually leads to a *stack-overflow*.

---

If your input arguments are non-negative integers, then you can implement it as follows:

**Recursively:**

```
unsigned long long power(unsigned long long x,unsigned int y)
{
    if (y == 0)
        return 1;
    return power(x,y/2)*power(x,y-y/2);
}
```

**Iteratively:**

```
unsigned long long power(unsigned long long x,unsigned int y)
{
    unsigned long long res = 1;
    while (y--)
        res *= x;
    return res;
}
```

**Efficiently:**

```
unsigned long long power(unsigned long long x,unsigned int y)
{
    unsigned long long res = 1;
    while (y > 0)
    {
        if (y & 1)
            res *= x;
        y >>= 1;
        x *= x;
    }
    return res;
}
```